# Codeigniter/jQuery: Having an issue fetching the values from a select dropdown list into a datatable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have a dropdown box which is fetching values from the database and a button, when the button is clicked the product in the dropdown box should display the product's details in the datatable. As of now when I click on the button to add the product into the datatable, nothing happens. I will post my code for MVC and the jQuery.

**MODEL:**

```
    public function getProductById($product_id){
    $query_product = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='".$product_id."'");
    return $query_product->result();
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function getProduct () {
    $prod_id = $this->input->post('pid');
    $this->load->model('order_m');
    $prod = $this->order_m->getProductById($prod_id);
    echo json_encode($prod);}
```

**VIEW:**

```
            <form > 
         <label>Select product</label>
            <select name="selectproduct" id="selectproduct">
                <option>Select a Product</option>
                <?php foreach ( $paid_products as $product ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $product->product_id ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="selectProduct" value="Add product to order">
        </form> 

<div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="display" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="width:25%;" >Product</th>
            <th style="width:25%;" >Sales Price</th>
            <th style="width:25%;" >Qty</th>
            <th style="width:25%;">Total</th>
            </tr>
            </thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table.container-fluid').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "agent/order/getProduct",
        "data": {"pid": product_id}
    },
    });
$('#selectProduct').click(function() {
    var id = this.value;
    var product = ('agent/order/getProduct'+id);
    table.ajax.url(product).load();
    table.reload();
    });
</script>
```

I will really be grateful if somebody could help me out with this. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Edit made based on Praveen Kumar's point.

Comment: console.log(); what is the console in your browser?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: product_id is not defined` I get this error

Comment: Replace **<option><?php echo $product->name; ?></option>** with **<option value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?></option>**

Comment: `$product->product_id` using just **id** was giving me an error

Answer (score 0):

Just maek two changes in your code:

Replace

```
<option><?php echo $product->name; ?></option>
```

With

```
<option value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><?php echo $product->name; ?></option>
```

And

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var product_id = '<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>';
$('table.container-fluid').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "agent/order/getProduct",
        "data": {"pid": product_id}
    },
    });
$('#selectProduct').click(function() {
    var id = $("#selectproduct").val();
    var product = ('agent/order/getProduct/'+id);
    table.ajax.url(product).load();
    table.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the `var id` need to be the same as the option value `product_id`?

Comment: Hi Amit, I have done your changes, still no effect. `Uncaught ReferenceError: product_id is not defined` This error is still being showed on console

Comment: That did clear that error, but now I am getting an error like this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`